# Transformation of point cloud in PCL - understanding of transformation values

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

i downloaded scans of standford bunny from [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/data/3Dscanrep/)

there is conf file, that contains transformations of scans, that looks like this:

`camera -0.0172 -0.0936 -0.734  -0.0461723 0.970603 -0.235889 0.0124573
bmesh bun000.ply 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
bmesh bun045.ply -0.0520211 -0.000383981 -0.0109223 0.00548449 -0.294635 -0.0038555 0.955586`

what i want to do is to get these 2 scans into the same coordinate system using point cloud library, but i don't understand values of these transformations

i found tutorials on 4x4 matrix transformations, is it possible to create 4x4 matrix from these values? or is this something completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about my answer, judging from the format I think it's `position_x position_y position_z quaternion_x quaternion_y quaternion_z quaternion_w` but please check with the code provided below

```py
from transforms3d.quaternions import quat2mat   
import numpy as np

# Create Identity transformation for 4x4
T = np.eye(4)

# Caution quat2mat uses w, x, y, z! Need to reorder your quaternion
T[:3, :3] = quat2mat([0.0124573, -0.0461723, 0.970603, -0.235889])

# Insert position x, y, z
T[:3, 3] = [-0.0172, -0.0936, -0.734]

# Print Result
print(T)                                                                     
# [[-0.99542587 -0.08375279  0.04596522 -0.0172    ]
#  [-0.09550694  0.8844491  -0.45675838 -0.0936    ]
#  [-0.00239911 -0.45905911 -0.88840249 -0.734     ]
#  [ 0.          0.          0.          1.        ]]
```